# Redeliver message from any step in route

Tags: error-handling, apache-camel

Camel has a RedeliveryErrorHandler that enables it to redeliver a message to the same step in case of an exception in the route.

I'm trying to find a way to replicate this behaviour, but have the message/headers come from an external source.
For example lets say the following route throws an exception during **Bean2.class** and we create an errorHandler that saves the current message/headers on that step to a file.

```
from("direct:inbound")
    .routeId("inbound-route")
    .bean(Bean.class)
    .bean(Bean2.class)
    .to("direct:outbound")
```

Afterwards I want to retry processing this message starting from the **Bean2.class** step.
Is there any way to do this in Camel or some custom functionality I could add that would make this possible?

Comment: @TacheDeChoco This [chapter](https://camel.apache.org/manual/exception-clause.html#_point_of_entry_for_redelivery_attempts) seems to imply otherwise?

Comment: You are right, sorry for the confusion. I will delete my comment right away.